How to deal with sequences that depends on all other terms
If you have a sequence of the form $A_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_kA_k=a_0A_0+a_1A_1+\dots+a_{n-1}A_{n-1}$, what should we do to make some general formula to $A_n$? I'll be grateful if someone can explain for me how to do this.

Note that $A_n=(1+a_{n-1})\times A_{n-1}$.

No, unfortunately, but it is not. Put n=1 and convince yourself

Sure, but for $n>1$ we have $A_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_kA_k=\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}a_kA_k+a_{n-1}A_{n-1}=A_{n-1}+a_{n-1}A_{n-1}=(1+a_{n-1})A_{n-1}$.  I agree that doesn't work for $n=1$.

This is a generalisation of Fibonacci sequence.

To summarize the discussion in the comments:
For $n=1$ we get $A_1=a_0A_0$.
For $n>1$ we write $$A_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_kA_k=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}a_kA_k\right)+a_{n-1}A_{n-1}=A_{n-1}+a_{n-1}A_{n-1}=(1+a_{n-1})A_{n-1}$$
It follows that $$\boxed {A_n=a_0\times A_0\times  \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(1+a_k)}$$

Thanks and sorry!!
